# Где находится boot.ini windows 10/2016

Tags: windows, windows-10

Хочу отредактировать файл boot.ini на сервере windows 2016 (или windows 10), не могу его найти, обычно он должен лежать на диске C:\ (в более поздних версиях).
команда в cmd:

```
bootcfg /query
ERROR: Cannot open BOOT.INI file.
```

По умолчанию этого файла нет, если его просто создать по адресу C:\boot.ini. файл игнорируется, видимо это пережиток windows xp.

Где находится и как называется данный файл?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нигде не находится и никак не называется.

См. справку по [BCDEdit](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc709667(v=ws.10).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Могу добавить к ответу Akina, что вместо штатного консольного `BCDEdit` мне намного удобнее оказалось воспользоваться бесплатной утилитой [EasyBCD](http://alternativeto.net/software/easybcd/).

С её помощью легко настроил dual-boot разных версий Windows, которые изначально были установлены по отдельности на разных дисках.